# JavaScript .not ignores the parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to validate all my inputs except the file uploader input. If I use `.not($( "#uploader" ))` it does ignore anything below I've written.

html:

```
<section>
        <div id="formularDiv" class="sampleFormStyle">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <h2><?php echo 'You\'re applaying for '.strtoupper($_GET['page']);?></h2>
                <form id="formularID">
                    <input id="firstName" name="firstName" type="text" placeholder="First Name:"/>
                    <input id="lastName" name="lastName" type="text" placeholder="Last Name:"/>
                    <input id="street" name="street" type="text" placeholder="Street:"/>
                    <input id="postalCode" name="postalCode" type="text" placeholder="Postal Code: " />
                    <input id="place" name="place" type="text" placeholder="Place: "/>
                    <input id="telefone" name="telefone" type="text" placeholder="Telefone: " />
                    <input id="email" name="email" type="email  " placeholder="Email: "/>
                    <textarea></textarea>
                    <label id="uploader" for="uploadFile"><i class="fa fa-cloud-upload fa-2x fa-fw" aria-hidden="true">Upload</i></label>
                    <input id="uploadFile" name="uploadFile" type="file"/>
                    <input id="submitForm" name="submitForm" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#formularID').submit(function() {
            $(":input").not('#uploader').each(function(){
                 //some code that's working without .not()
            });
})
```

I appreciate every help!

Comment: you are trying to target selector of type 'input'. You should just do $('input')

Comment: hey thanks for your replay. I did but it does still fail

Comment: could you post the relevant html to understand the issue ?

Comment: yes of course. I'll need a few secounds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.    As per your html, the id of the input that you want ignore is uploadFile not uploader

```
$('#formularID').submit(function() {
            $("input:not(#uploadFile)").each(function(){
                 //some code that's working without .not()
            });
    })
```

Comment: thanks for helping but it does still not working. It does check my file upload and this returns always a number. And numbers aren't valid for my inputs. But I'll add some details to my post!

Comment: @This.Sven Can you give the html of your uploader input

Comment: Thank you for your help and I'm sorry if I wasn't clear enough

Answer (score 0):

try using .filter() of jquery

```
$( "input" ).filter(function( index ) {
    return $( this ).attr( "id" ) != "uploadFile";
}).each(function(){
    // your code
});
```

Comment: Thank you but the answer from @rishabh dev did work!

Comment: nice alternate solution.